# Capturar datetime ajax com jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho um array contendo alguns objetos de uma chamada AJAX. Os valores estão sendo passados por meio de um data: "**res.data.tags**"

Em umas das respostas objetivo o seguinte resultado:

```
2016-07-15T10:00:00-0300
```

Como faço para capturar apenas o valor de **"10:00"** do datetime acima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a biblioteca [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) para converter data/hora. Exemplo:

```
moment('2016-07-15T10:00:00-0300').format('hh:mm');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j51b2mqn/